# for loop in C/C++

Tags: c

I have for loop doubt  that I need to ask .

once i saw in coding something like

```
for(i = 0; i<10; i+)
```

My doubt is why &when  in for loop we use say `i+` or `i-` rather than `i++` or `i--`

Thanks in advance

Comment: we don't. that code doesn't compile

Comment: `i+`?  Are you sure it wasn't `+i`?  `i+` is not even a valid expression.

Comment: This code does not work you should use i++, i-- not i+, i-

Comment: Why all of the downvotes? This seems like a genuine question to me.

Comment: @Draksis: The people who do the majority of voting on Stackoverflow are a little stricter (IMHO) than other forums. People will probably disagree with me for saying that, but, that's why it is my opinion.

Comment: i saw that code in my company's product. I didnt have an environment at that time to compile the code. But as far as I rem the code had i- and not i--.

Comment: I imagine it's being downvoted because it shows a serious lack of research on the samprat's part.

Comment: just for curiosity purpose , may i please know what was wrong in the question that i got 2 downvotes. it will help me to be more attentive while asking qs

Comment: @Draksis: From the tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: Thanks nil for clarification. I will make sure that from next time I will do more research before asking question. But I did try to find something in google but was not successful thats why i posted in forum

Comment: @samprat: That you didn't try compiling it yourself, and seeing that it didn't work, indicates that you didn't do any "research effort".

Comment: @samprat: I didn't downvote, but I think that the downvoters feel that you should have at least tried to compile such code before asking this question; you would have noticed immediately that it results in a compilation error, because the "unary postfix + operator" doesn't exist.

Comment: i do accept that i have not compiled  the code.I will make sure that in future I will properly investigate before firing the question.Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work, doesn't the compiler return an error if you do? ( or atleast a warning.. )

Just use ++i or i++

Answer (score 2):

Using `i+` instead of `i++` should not work. As I think you know, `i++` increases the value of `i` by one. When the compiler sees `i+`, it is expecting something after the `+`, which causes it to not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The line in question is not valid C

> for(i = 0; i<10; i+)

Some valid, equivalent (between themselves) options are

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
for(i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
for(i = 0; i < 10; ) { /*...*/ i++; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use i+ or i- because if doesn’t work i.e doesn’t increase or decrease value of i for increment you have may use i++,++i,i+=1,i=i+1 and for decrement you can use these by changing sign to negtive